# Where does Spring's <import resource=""> get its configuration from? Sees some app-contexts but not others?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

Working on a large project I just got assigned to and I am new to J2EE/Spring/Maven and the project consists of ~20 modules.

I cant seem to figure out why in a Module A,  works, but  can not find the resource, even if [Module B].xml has the same code as common.xml. Where are some possible locations/configurations/code I can look to figure out where the resource context is coming from?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do and which is the problem you have. Thanks.

Comment: If not prefix anything, it can be relative path or absolute path depends on your settings. foo.xml relative path. /foo/foo.xml absolute. You can prefix classpath: to load from classpath or classpath*: to load class path and also imported jar. Always find the root application Context.xml and trace to others xml.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure of what you are asking but first read [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/beans.html) about importing resources. There it says:

> All location paths are considered relative to the definition file doing the importing.